# WPF services for YES/NO MessageBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

With reference to [What exactly are "WPF services"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925017/what-exactly-are-wpf-services) and its attachment https://digitaltapestry.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/services-%E2%80%93-your-viewmodel-death-star/ .
Using services in `WPF MVVM` application, Can i use this type of service in *ViewModel* even to display MessageBox with Yes No Cancel buttons?
If yes, whitch data type should i return in `ViewModel (Boolean  Yes=> true No/Cancel => false) (MessageBoxResult)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i use this type of service in ViewModel even to display `MessageBox` with Yes No Cancel buttons?

Yes.

> If yes, whitch data type should i return in ViewModel (Boolean Yes=> true No/Cancel => false) (`MessageBoxResult`)?

The service should return a `bool?`, .e.g.:

```
public class DisplayMessageService : IDisplayMessage
{
    public bool? ShowDialog(string message)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, "title...", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                return true;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                return false;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you simply display a `MessageBox` without any "Yes" or "No" button, you shouldn't return anything from the method.