# Accessing a MainWindow list from another window (Protection)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mainwindow

I have this code over here from MainWindow.xaml.cs in a WPF application

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    animaciones.Preferences Preferences;
    animaciones.GameOver GameOver;
    ObservableCollection<Figura> listafiguras = new ObservableCollection<Figura>();
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    Raton raton;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Preferences = new animaciones.Preferences();
        GameOver = new animaciones.GameOver();
        raton = new Raton();
        player.SoundLocation = "lostwoods.wav";
        Canvas.SetLeft(raton.fig, raton.x);
        Canvas.SetBottom(raton.fig, raton.y);
        lienzo.Children.Add(raton.fig);

        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(KeyDownEventos);

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += OnTick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);


    }
```

I want to use the "listafiguras" ObservableCollection in another xaml.cs like this:

```
 public partial class Preferences : Window
{


    public Preferences()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabla.ItemsSource = MainWindow.listafiguras;
    }
```

But it says MainWindow is not accesible due its protection level. How can I change that to give access to my variable? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

listafiguras is private to your MainWindow class and thus not accessible to anything outside of Mainwindow. You can perhaps pass this list as a constructor parameter to Preferences :

```
public Preferences(ObservableCollection<Figura> figuraList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabla.ItemsSource = figuraList;
    }
```

In MainWindow:

```
Preferences = new animaciones.Preferences(listafiguras );
```

However i suggest you look into using services and DI frameworks for sharing data between views for a more general solution to this type of problem (see [What exactly are "WPF services"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925017/what-exactly-are-wpf-services))

Comment: I tried it! Now it says this: parameter type 'ObservableCollection<Figura>' is less accessible than method 'Preferences.Preferences(ObservableCollection<Figura>)

Comment: What's the accessibility of Figura (private, public) ?

Comment: public Figura(){}

Comment: Yeah it worked! I just put public class Figura instead of only class Figure.. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Great, but look into using interfaces / services to wrap shared data and have these interfaces injected into your views as that link in my answer describes.