# deterministic and asynchronous field validation in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, mvvm

In my MVVM based application I need to validate fields in a data entry from. If possible, I would like to use the standard WPF validation binding with ErrorTemplates.

However I would like the execution of the validation logic to be completely driven/triggered by the  ViewModel (push to the View, not pull by the View) for the following reasons:

1. It must work asynchronously because validation logic might take a while to execute.
2. I need to be more deterministic and fine grained when validation logic is to be executed (e.g. only after the user clicks "Apply" or when the internal state changed in a way that entries suddenly become invalid)

I know Silverlight has `INotifyDataErrorInfo` which was introduced for exactly this purpose, but WPF doesn't. How can I still have my validation logic exectuted deterministically and asynchronously?

Comment: It seems that it is just not possible, so I need to go a different route as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293277/create-a-visualtree-off-of-a-control-template-in-code

Comment: Note that WPF 4.5 introduced support similar to Silverlight for  INotifyDataErrorInfo, here for example: http://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an answer on your other question that apparently answered this one too.

[Create a visualtree off of a control template in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293277/create-a-visualtree-off-of-a-control-template-in-code/7330345#7330345)

Answer (score 0):

The built in validation for WPF and Silverlight is meant for quick client-side validation (such as Regex, parsing values, etc.).

If you need to go to a server to perform validation (or validation takes a long time), I would do that in a custom way.  Such as when clicking a save button, etc.

So say you have a Save method in a ViewModel (you don't mention which MVVM framework you use):

```
public void Save()
{
     //Do your validation, this might start a new thread (I use Async CTP myself)

     //If validation is good, do your extra work, else display validation errors
}
```

I would just do all the work required for this within an action in your ViewModel

Comment: So you are saying, I can't use the ErrorTemplates? I need to rely on he built in error templates of the WPF and custom controls. e.g. I would like to show the standard red border around a invalid textbox. How can I force this border to be shown?

Comment: I was suggesting to use a method like the top answer suggests here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921601/how-can-i-handle-a-validation-error-in-my-viewmodel-instead-of-my-views-code-beh .  I don't think it is a good idea to use the built-in validation if it's going to be a long running operation (it will always lock up the UI).

Comment: I still need to materialize some sort of "ErrorTemplate" and display it once the VM raises an event. Since some of my forms unfortunately have quite a lot of fields I would not want the error visuals do be part of the visual tree right away but should only be created (e.g. by a behavior) once an validation error occurred for that field: See more info in my followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293277/create-a-visualtree-off-of-a-control-template-in-code