# Create a visualtree off of a control template in code

Tags: wpf, validation, controltemplate

This is a follow up question to a previous question, wich didn't really get me anywhere:
 [deterministic and asynchronous field validation in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281264/deterministic-and-asynchronous-field-validation-in-wpf)

Since WPF doesn't support [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) it seems, that I need to implement something like that myself (please correct me if I am wrong here). I need this because I want the ViewModel to trigger when to display special ErrorTemplates for certain fields (e.g. after the click of a button or after the end of a long running async validation operation or when the internal state changes in a way that certain fields suddenly become invalid).

I am considering to write a custom markup extension or behavior for this. It listens to my version of `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implemented by the ViewModel and creates a VisualTree from a special wellknown ErrorTemplate defined in XAML once the `ErrorsChanged` event was raised.

Once I have defined that template in XAML, how do I find it from my behavior/expression, materialize an actual  visual tree out of it and then display it (probably somehow on an adorner layer) at the right field entry on my form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asynchronous field validation in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281264/asynchronous-field-validation-in-wpf)

Comment: Have you tried [bindinggroups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/11/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation.aspx)? Because they can be used for per-form validation. BindingGroups allow to trigger the validation at least what i can see from the documentation, never used them myself. Another link [BindingGroups validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/09/08/wpf-bindinggroup-and-validation-feedback.aspx)

Comment: @dowhilefor If I understand this correctly I would need a reference to the `BindingGroup` in my ViewModel to explicitly trigger validation from my ViewModel.

Comment: Or you could create an ICommand call it ValidateCommand put this as a DP into your control/form and Bind it to your ViewModel. The implementation of this command is in your control/form. In the viewmodel you now just need to call Execute on this bound command to trigger the validation. That way your ViewModel doesn't need to know of BindingGroup. Like i said, never used them before, but i guess this would be the way i would do it. I like keeping the WPF stuff out of my VM as much as possible.

Comment: How would I trigger the validation in that command so that WPF will display the ErrorTemplate (or hide it, when it validates)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a markup extension. I recently found myself wishing for the same behavior, so I created a solution that works for my needs. Hopefully this helps you as well.

The `IDataErrorInfo` interface actually contains everything we need in order to do asynchronous signaling. What it lacks is an event system to trigger notifications automatically. There is a relationship between that interface and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The combination of the two actually allows you to signal a change, somewhat indirectly.

First the control:

```
<TextBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Width="100"
    Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
        Path=Id,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" />
```

Pretty straightforward. The value of `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not important, and `NotifyOnValidationError` is not required, but won't hurt anything if you add it.

Next, the view model, which is just a contrived example. The important part is in the `IDataErrorInfo` indexer.

```
public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get{ return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Id" ) );
        }
    }

    public string this[ string columnName ]
    {
        get
        {
            object result = AsynchValidationCoordinator.GetError( columnName );
            if ( result != null )
            {
                return result.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`AsynchValidationCoordinator` is a class that tracks properties and any associated error information. For illustrative purposes, the key being used is just the property name, but you could as easily create a compound key to differentiate potential property collisions in scenarios with multiple view models.

```
public static class AsynchValidationCoordinator
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> ErrorList = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public static void CancelError( string propertyName, object error )
    {
        object value;
        ErrorList.TryRemove( propertyName, out value );
    }

    public static object GetError( string propertyName )
    {
        object error = null;
        if ( ErrorList.ContainsKey( propertyName ) )
        {
            ErrorList.TryRemove( propertyName, out error );
        }
        return error;
    }

    public static void RegisterError( string propertyName, object error )
    {
        ErrorList[propertyName] = error;
    }
}
```

Tracking property names is necessary, but you could create an entirely different way of tracking them, including tracking the names within the view model. This was just an easy way for me to apply a structured form quickly to an existing project.

So tying this all together, I added the following `ICommand` property to the test view model and bound it to a Button. (`RelayCommand` is from Josh Smith's [MSDN MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).)

```
public ICommand ValidateCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand( Validate );
    }
}

private void Validate( object value )
{
    Thread thread = new Thread( RaiseChanged );
    thread.Start();
}

private void RaiseChanged()
{
    Thread.Sleep( 3000 );
    AsynchValidationCoordinator.RegisterError( "Id", "Error Message Goes Here" );
    this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Id" ) );
}
```

The source of the call is irrelevant. The important point that ties all of this together is the fact that once `PropertyChanged` is called, the `IDataErrorInfo` indexer follows in its tracks. Returning the error information that was registered in `AsynchValidationCoordinator` triggers the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the control with the relevant error message.

Comment: +1 for the idea to tie `IDataErrorInfo` together with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Didn't think of that. If I understand this correctly you just trigger an **additional** PropertyChanged event whenever you want the validation error to be displayed or removed to force WPF to reevaluate the validation in `public string this[string columnName]`. Is that correct?

Comment: It feels a bit hackish but it is probably still better than rolling my own MarkupExtension and ErrorTemplate implementation. I suppose that WPF vNext will bring `INotifyDataErrorInfo` from Sliverlight: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568212/inotifydataerrorinfo-for-wpf

Comment: The external coordinator class probably contributes to making it feel that way. At least it did for me. I actually modified the base view model class in my own design to track the errors within the view model, rather than rely on an external collection. It gets me closer to the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation, and with a little effort, I could probably roll a model that almost matched the syntax exactly, although pre-vNext, it would still require `IDataErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

`INotifyDataErrorInfo` is now included in **WPF 4.5** along with a lot of other features. See the following links

- [What's New in WPF Version 4.5 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#INotifyDataErrorInfo)

Here is the link to the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh127353

Comment: Yes, once WPF 4.5 is available (2012?), this is an option. Unfortunately I can't wait that long.

Comment: @bitbonk: I just wanted to point out that it's available to use in the Developer Preview, to you and anyone else that comes across this question. And when it's officially released it's not only an option, but what should be used since it'll be fully implemented.